# Can someone tell me what kind of airplane this is?

Tags: aircraft-identification

It says Capt Nungesser on the tail. I’ve researched him but can’t find out what type of plane this is. French?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The aircraft with the inscription on the rudder "Capt Nungesser" is the French aircraft "Potez VIII" 1922 model type, the second version, equipped with a 70 hp. Anzani engine.

http://www.airwar.ru/enc/law1/potez8.html

Here is one picture from that site:

[image: Potez VIII side view]

Comment: Great find! +1.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should supersede mine.

Comment: Apparently Nungesser brought three planes to the US for his barnstorming flying circus: the Potez, a Nieuport 18 and a Hanriot HD1. Remarkably the Hanriot has survived and is on display in California. https://earlyaviators.com/enunges3.htm

Answer (score -1):

Fairly certain it's a [Breguet Br. 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%A9guet_14)

Do you have any other pictures, or a higher quality one?

Comment: The tail is a lot different between the one you suggest and the picture the OP provided.

Comment: Not only the tail - the upper wing has distinct dihedral which is missing on the Breguet.

Comment: In the photo you linked to, the leading edge of the lower wing is nearly at the level of the bystander's shoulders.  Compare to the photo in the question...